# 「Webサイトでの個人情報入力の代用となるファイルについて」という質問はオフトピックか

Tags: 討議

[Webサイトでの個人情報入力の代用となるファイルについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33859/5793) という質問がオフトピックでクローズされていますが、クローズ理由を説明するコメントが1つもついてません。

「こういう目的に使うための共通フォーマットはあるか」はプログラムに密接した話題であるのは明白で、この質問がオフトピックとされる理由が私には全くわかりません。

｢公開鍵暗号の鍵をやりとりするためのフォーマットはありますか？」(PEMとか)、「Web APIでデータを送受信するのに適したフォーマットはありますか？」(汎用ならJSONとかXMLとか、特定用途ならRSSとか)もオフトピックなんでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

かなり誤解を恐れず書きます。

まず、質問文がとても長いので質問文頭の要約を見てレビューを判断されるかと思います。

> **質問内容**
>   Webサイトでの個人情報入力の代用となるファイルが存在すると便利だと思うのですが、 これは既に存在しますか。またはどこかで提案されたことがあるでしょうか。

この場合、"個人情報入力の代用となるファイルを探している"と私には読み取れました。
質問の本来の意図は「個人情報入力の代用で認証ファイルなどを使用する技術はあるか？」かと思うのですが、「ファイルを探している」という箇所に収束されてしまうと、お買い物質問っぽくなり主観的と判断されオフトピックになる可能性が高いのではないでしょうか？
長くなる場合、要約する文章が重要になるかと思いますので、
レビュワーや、質問を見た閲覧者が読み砕けるのであれば要約文を編集してあげるのも手ではないでしょうか？
勿論、クローズする際にはクローズ理由を書いてもらうというのも大前提ではありますが……

---

また、JSONファイル云々などの言葉の問題ですが、
質問者は大抵、用語や単語を知らないかと思いますので、
「形式が固定されているのでフォーマットについて聞いているのではない」と断定するのは早計かと思います。
どういったことが聞きたいのか判断できないのであれば、一度コメントでやり取りしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: レビュアーが「文頭の要約を見て判断」していたのであれば不適切なレビューだったということになると思います

Answer (score 1):

当該質問の投稿者です。ありがとうございます。

確かに、質問以外の詳細仕様の説明の分量が多いので、
「質問形式で提案している、感想を求めている」と取られてしまう可能性はあると
思っていました。

しかし、目的のフォーマットが既存かどうかを知りたいのは、本当です。
既存であれば、それがなぜ使われないのか、という理由を知りたいです。
既存でなければ、作れない理由があるのか、誰も言い出していないのかを知りたいです。
もし作れない理由があって、それを解決することができるなら、
私自身が規格を作りたいと思うほど、そういったフォーマットには価値があると思っています。

これは、そういったフォーマットを、私自身が「ユーザーとして」欲しいという気持ちです。
特許を取ってビジネスしようという意図はありませんし、
どなたかがそういう形で実現してくださるのなら、満足です。

フォーマットが既存であるかは、
下記ワードでGoogle検索してみましたが、見つかりませんでした。

・「個人情報　アップロード」
　- 画像アップロードによる個人情報流出の危険性についての情報がヒットしました。

・「個人情報ファイル」
　- 個人情報保護法の用語「個人情報ファイル」がヒットしました。
　　この用語は個人情報データベースを意味するようです。フォーマットではありません。

ーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
（追記）
お二方、質問の問題点のご指摘をいただき、ありがとうございます。

読み解く努力をしていただけたことに感謝いたします。
しかし誤解を受ける時点で、私の質問が悪いですし、正直なところ、
質問を投稿した時点で、当サイトのガイドラインに違反しているかもしれない、
という気は少なからずしていました。
ひとまず、仕様についての記述は当該質問から削除いたします。

Answer (score 1):

クローズに投票した6人のうちの1人です。私がどうして「オフトピック」扱いでこの質問にクローズ投票したのかを書きます。

まず私は、この質問が「こういう目的に使うための共通フォーマットはあるか」という類のものだと受け取れませんでした。なぜなら[私が閲覧したときの質問本文](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33859/3)には「形式はJSONです」と書かれていたためです。当該目的に使用するためのよいファイル形式を聞いているわけではないのだな、と判断しました。(この時点で多少user21441さんの意図を汲み取れていなかったということは認めます。)

次に、たとえばAPI設計の質問のように、システムのデザインに関する質問なのかどうかを考えました。しかしこれも違うらしいと思いました。「個人情報ファイル」として扱おうとしている情報は適当な個人情報であればとりあえず何でもよく、むしろご質問の主体は「個人情報を一括管理したい」というところにあるように思えました。

最後に、この質問が個人情報をテーマとしているため、暗号学的な知見を求めてらっしゃるのかどうか考えました。しかしこの質問からはそういった事情は汲み取れず、むしろ「個人情報ファイル」自体はTLSなどを使ってよしなに送受信されることを想定しているのではないか、と思いました。

この上で、[ヘルプセンターで決められているトピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)を見て、

- プログラミング上の具体的な問題、または …… プログラミングと直接は関係しない。
- アルゴリズムに関する問題、または …… アルゴリズムの問題ではない。
- プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題であり …… そうではない。
- ソフトウェア開発に固有の、実際的で回答可能な問題である …… 微妙だが、固有ではなさそうだ。つまり、もっと上流の問題にも見えました。

と判断し、さらに私がこの質問を見たときには既にオフトピックを理由とするクローズ票が2つ集まっていたため、そこに追加で票を投じたというわけです。

白状すると、クローズ票を投じたときも、微妙なラインの質問だなあとは思っていました。もしこの質問が「〜というファイルを準備すれば良いように思うのですが、皆さんはどう思いますか？」という形式だったら、迷わずクローズしたでしょう（[「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)に載っているパターンと同じだからです)。しかしこの質問はこれとは少し違い、「既に提案されたことはありますか？」という形になっていました。もしこの質問が「〜という形で個人情報を管理したいと考えているのですが、類似した既存の技術があればそれに乗っかろうと思っています。既存の技術はありますか？」という形だったのであれば、これは「プログラミング上の具体的な問題」であり、クローズ対象にはならないと考えたでしょう。

そういう訳で、私はもしこの質問が上手く編集され、プログラミング上の具体的な問題やソフトウェア開発に固有の問題に関する質問であることが分かりやすくなれば、再オープン可能だと思っています。特に、[user21441さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2454/19110)にあるように、もしご質問の本質が「〇〇という形式で個人情報を管理する既存技術は存在するか」というところにあるのでしたら、「個人情報入力の代用となるファイルの仕様イメージ」という節は蛇足だったのかもしれません。おそらく私はこの節を読んでご質問を誤解していました（すいません）。

追記： [この編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33859/5)を見て再オープンを推薦しました。

Comment: 問いかけの形式程度でオフトピックかどうかの判断が分かれる、というのは判断の基準が厳しすぎるように思います。

Comment: @suzukis うーん、大抵の場合はその通りだと思いますが、境界線上だとなかなか微妙なケースもあるのではないかと思います。たとえば「Web APIでデータを送受信するのに適したフォーマットはありますか？　現状〜という形を使っているのですが、乗り換えを考えています。」と「現状〜という形のデータフォーマットを用いてWeb APIでデータを送受信しています。皆さんは何を使用していますか？」は大体聞いている内容が同じように思えもする一方、後者が[「どのような質問は避けるべきですか？」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)に該当しないかどうかは微妙なラインな気がします。どういう意味で問いたいかというのは重要な問題ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 一般論ではなく、「既に提案されたことはありますか？」「既存の技術はありますか？」の違いです。

Comment: @suzukis なるほど。そこは確かにほとんど同じことを言っていますね。本質は、私から見てこの質問の最初の版が「わたしの考えたフォーマットは良いと思いませんか」みたいな形だと思ってしまったところなので、言葉のあやっぽいです。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「わたしの考えたフォーマッ‌​トは良いと思いませんか」だからオフトピックというのも理解できません。

Comment: @suzukis それは、解決すべき実際の問題がないからです。

Comment: 上に書かれていたことからも感じたのですが、質問を「オフトピックにするためにルールを解釈する」努力をされていませんか？

Comment: @suzukis 自分でそう思ったことはありませんね……。私としてはおそらく逆で、自分の中でこういう風にルールを適用しているんですがコミュニティとしてそれで良いですか、ということを確認するためのMetaなんじゃないかと思っていました。私はSEを初めてまだ数カ月しか経っていないので、私のルールの付け方がデファクトと異なるようでしたら、教えていただきたいです。